# she forgot to ___ her sources

Tags: grammar, word-choice

I've a sentence which I doubt if it's grammaticality correct or not. Can you take a look?

> She wasn't succesful on her english exam because she forgot to ______ her sources.
>
> a) cite
>   b) resight
>   c) sight
>   d) site

I had done it as *sight*. It makes a sense to me, doesnt it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer is a) cite.

"Cite" is a verb, meaning in this case to refer to a source. There are two reasons to cite a source: authority and credit. One can cite from a reputable source to validate the correctness of the information presented. The second reason is to properly assign credit of work that other people have done that one is using, to distinguish from one's own work. These two reasons are not mutually exclusive. (That is, one can freely do so for one reason, the other reason or both).

"Site" is a noun, meaning a place or location.

"Sight" is a noun means the ability to see, what is seen, or an aiming mechanism (generally used in plural form).

Note that all three of these options are pronounced identically.

Comment: However, it seems ''Resight'' on my answer key.

Comment: @Hamilton - Why are you providing that vital piece of information down here, instead of including it in your question? Moreover, are you sure you copied the question correctly? It should be "English exam", not "english exam".

Comment: "Sight" is also a verb. (It doesn't fit in the question's sentence, but it's not just a noun.)